How to draw L.Polyline across Pacific/Antimeridian when locations are wrapped using wrap() method?
We are developing a game called GuessWhereYouAre.com, where players explore random locations around the world. We use Leaflet's L.Polyline to draw paths between locations, but we're running into an issue when trying to draw a polyline across the Pacific Ocean (around the antimeridian).
We're using the wrap() method to handle locations wrapping (so when users place a point behind antimeridian, it's corrected for better distance calculation and multiplayer mode), but then when we draw, the polyline will not cross the antimeridian since all points are wrapped. The line wraps around the entire map instead of drawing a shorter path across the Pacific (see screenshot, you can also get a repro in the game too: https://guesswhereyouare.com - select Philippines map and guess location in Hawaii).
For distance calculation Turf.js is handling this fine internally, it's just leaflet doesn't draw shortest path.
Is there a recommended way to handle this scenario? We want to ensure that the polyline correctly wraps across the antimeridian without creating long lines around the world. Any tips or best practices would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks for your help!


For now I got an ugly solution where I check if (Math.abs(target.lng - locationToWrap.lng) > 180.0) then add/substract 360 and check if again but I don't think it's the right fix.
